# python Django - Convert SQL Query to ORM Query(Subquery)

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

```
SELECT *,
        (SELECT sum(amount) FROM history
         WHERE history_id IN
                        (SELECT history_id FROM web_cargroup
                         WHERE group_id = a.group_id) AND type = 1)
        as sum
          FROM web_car a;
```

It is very difficult to convert the above query to orm
1. orm annotate is automatically created by group by.
2. It is difficult to put a subquery in the 'in' condition

please help.

Comment: Just use raw queries and be done with it..  ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/ )

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the models you presented, this should work

```
from django.db.models import Sum

History.objects.filter(
    type=1,
    id__in=(CarGroup.objects.values('history_id'))
).aggregate(
    total_amount=Sum('amount')
)
```

Comment: I want to get all the information in the web_car table.